# TypeError: Getting multiple Artist IDs from the Spotify API

Tags: typeerror, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to get a list of multiple Artist IDs from the Spotify API using Spotipy and artist names. The Spotify docs say you can grab up to 50 at a time. If I try this:

```
names = ["push baby", "rkls", "seiji oda", "slowthai"]
results = spotify.search(q='artist:' + names, type='artist')
```

...I get this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

When I try this:

```
names = ["push baby", "rkls", "seiji oda", "slowthai"]
results = spotify.search(q=['artist:' + f"{x}" for x in names], type='artist')
```

...it just gives me just the ID for the first item in the list, "push baby".

If I try this:

```
names = ["push baby", "rkls", "seiji oda", "slowthai"]
results = for x in names: spotify.search(q=['artist:' + f"{x}"], type='artist')
```

...it gives me an Invalid Syntax error.

Any suggestions how I should be writing this?

Thanks!
Matthew

edit: here's the more complete code I'm using, with four variations, none of which work:

```
names = ["push baby", "rkls", "seiji oda", "slowthai"]

# results = spotify.search(q='artist:' + names[2], limit=50, type='artist')
# results = spotify.search(q=['artist:' + f"{x}" for x in names], limit=50, type='artist')
# results = for x in names: spotify.search(q=['artist:' + f"{x}"], limit=50, type='artist')
results = spotify.search(q=["push baby", "rkls", "seiji oda", "slowthai"], limit=50, type='artist')

items = results['artists']['items']

artist = items[0]
print(artist['name'], artist['id'])
```

Comment: I'm inclined to think the first one should work as is. If I use q=['artist:' + f"{x}" for x in names[0]] it successfully returns the ID just the first item of that list, "push baby". That leads me to think if I just leave that [0] off it should work for the entire list, yet that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Spotify docs it looks like you can specify up to 50 returns but just one request, which means the 1200 artists will have to be done one by one. Doh!